# Markov Process for fuel consumption

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-process, applications, poisson-process

Say I have a gas station where cars arrive to refuel. I know that if the waiting times between arrivals is exponentially distributed with mean $1/\lambda$ time-units, then I can model the number of cars arriving in $(0,t]$ as a Poisson process $N_t$ with mean rate $\lambda$ per time unit - which is Markov.

However, now I want to model the amount of fuel contained in the gas station - that is, for every unit time period (say every hour) I check to see how much fuel was taken by the cars that came to refuel. Would making the quantity of the hourly fuel consumption exponentially distributed make this a Markov process?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "I know that if the rate at which the cars arrive is exponential I can create a Poisson process which is Markov" More exactly, if the *waiting times* between arrivals is exponentially distributed with mean $1/\lambda$ time-units, then you can model the *number of cars arriving* in $(0,t]$ as a Poisson process $N_t$ with *mean rate* $\lambda$ per time unit.

Comment: Regarding the amount of fuel, the sensible model is a *compound Poisson process*. The amount of fuel consumed at time $t$ is given by $Y_t = \sum_{k=1}^{N_t} C_i$ where $C_1,C_2,\dotsc$ are IIDRVs that are all $\geq0$ representing the amount of fuel consumed by the 1st, 2nd, etc customers. If $F_0$ is the total fuel at the station at time $0$, then $F_t=F_0-Y_t$ is the fuel leftover at time $t$. An exponentially distributed fuel consumption is certainly one valid possibility. The compound process is always Markov provided the summands are IID or Markov themselves.